# Open a native application in fullscreen from my custom Home Screen

Tags: android, homescreen, android-launcher, kiosk-mode, android-fullscreen

I am developing a custom Home Screen (Kiosk mode) where an admin user can manage the applications that will be available for common users.

I already blocked back button, home button and put the application in fullscreen.

When the admin user provides access to a native application on my main screen, I am able to open it using:

```
ApplicationInfo app = (ApplicationInfo) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
startActivity(mPackageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(app.packageName));
```

For example, if I want to open the Calculator, I start the activity by its package name:

```
com.android.calculator2
```

The problem is that when I open the Calculator, the notification bar appears and I can't control it, allowing the user to access other applications that admin didn't allow.

Is it possible to hide the notification bar for all the system while running my custom Home Screen or open the native application on a Window that I could control?

Thank you.